# Recursively kill R process with children in linux

Tags: linux, r, shell, process, fork

I am looking for a general method to launch and then kill an R process, including possibly all forks or other processes that it invoked.

For example, a user runs a script like this:

```
library(multicore);
for(i in 1:3) parallel(foo <- "bar");
for(i in 1:3) system("sleep 300", wait=FALSE);
for(i in 1:3) system("sleep 300&");
q("no")
```

After the user quits the R session, the child processes are still running:

```
jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~$ ps -ef | grep R
jeroen    4469     1  0 16:38 pts/1    00:00:00 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
jeroen    4470     1  0 16:38 pts/1    00:00:00 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
jeroen    4471     1  0 16:38 pts/1    00:00:00 /usr/lib/R/bin/exec/R
jeroen    4502  4195  0 16:39 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto R
jeroen@jeroen-ubuntu:~$ ps -ef | grep "sleep"
jeroen    4473     1  0 16:38 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 300
jeroen    4475     1  0 16:38 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 300
jeroen    4477     1  0 16:38 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 300
jeroen    4479     1  0 16:38 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 300
jeroen    4481     1  0 16:38 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 300
jeroen    4483     1  0 16:38 pts/1    00:00:00 sleep 300
jeroen    4504  4195  0 16:39 pts/1    00:00:00 grep --color=auto sleep
```

To make things worse, their their parent process id is 1 making it hard to identify them. Is there a method to run an R script in a way that allows me to recursively kill the process and its children at any time?

Edit: so I don't want to manually have to go in to search & kill processes. Also I don't want to kill all R processes, as there might be others that are doing fine. I need a method to kill a specific process and all of its children.

Comment: Just don't kill PID 1 - it will *not* do what you want. Well, actually it will... sort of...

Comment: lol @thkala oh yes it will do more than he bargained for :) and why not simply remove this binary?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is mainly about the *multicore* part. Children are waiting for you to collect the results - see `?collect`. Normally, you should never use `parallel` without a provision to clean up, typically in `on.exit`. *multicore* cleans up in high-level functions like `mclapply`, but if you use lower-level functions it is your responsibility to perform the cleanup (since *multicore* cannot know if you left the children running intentionally or not).

Your example is really bogus, because you don't even consider collecting results. But anyway, if that is really what you want, you'll have to do the cleanup at some point. For example, if you want to terminate all children on exit, you could define `.Last` like this:

```
 .Last <- function(...) {
     collect(wait=FALSE)
     all <- children()
     if (length(all)) {
         kill(all, SIGTERM)
         collect(all)
     }
 }
```

Again, the above is **not** a recommended way to deal with this - it rather a last resort. You should really assign jobs and collect results like

```
jobs <- lapply(1:3, function(i) parallel({Sys.sleep(i); i}))
collect(jobs)
```

As for the general process child question - `init` inherits the children only after `R` quits, but in `.Last` you can still find their pids since the parent process exists at that point so you could perform similar cleanup as in the *multicore* case.

Comment: Thanks. The problem is that users sometimes (I suppose unintentionally) leave a mess on my servers. I'm trying to sandbox it down by restricting permissions and clean up after them wherever possible.

Comment: +1 This is good advice, and helpfully extends the documentation.  Not that the documentation for `multicore` is bad, dear author of `multicore`, but mastering `fork` and `collect` is made easier with more examples and advice.

Comment: @Jeroen That is fair enough. Unfortunately clean up in R is voluntary. However, you could write a small C function and register it with `atexit` to force cleanup in all cases (except for crashes - only signal handlers will help with those).

Comment: @Iterator Well, you're not supposed to use `fork` - there is even a warning about that ;). Most users should be happy with `mclapply`. But it's fair enough - I can add an extra warning about the life of the children on the `parallel`/`collect` page.

Comment: I think the best thing I can think of right now is `.Last <- function() system("pkill -P 1 R")` which will kill all R orphans...

Answer (score 4):

*Before* the user quits the R session, the processes you want to kill will have parent process ID equal to the process ID of the session that started them.  You could perhaps use the `.Last` or `.Last.sys` hooks (see `help(q)`) to kill all processes with the appropriate PPID at that point; those can be suppressed with `q(runLast=FALSE)`, so it isn't perfect, but I think it's the best option you have.

*After* the user quits the R session, there is no reliable way to do what you want -- the only record the kernel keeps of process parentage is the PPID you see in `ps -ef`, and when a parent process exits, that information is destroyed, as you have discovered.

Note that if one of the *child* processes forks, the grandchild will have PPID equal to the *child*'s PID, and that will get reset to 1 when the *child* exits, which it might do before the grandparent exits.  Thus, there is no reliable way to catch *all* of a process's descendants in general, even if you do so before the process exits.  (One hears that "cgroups" provide a way, but one is unfamiliar with the details; in any case, that is an optional feature which only some iterations/configurations of the Linux kernel provide, and is not available at all elsewhere.)

Comment: You may also want to look at `ps aux --forest`, which gives the same information as the PPID (it has to be done before the parent dies), more graphically. It is useful if you have several generations of processes.

Comment: Unfortunately, even before the parent process dies, children that have been started with the system() command will have parent id 1.

Comment: @Jeroen Not necessarily: for instance `system("sleep 300")` won't, but `system("sleep 300 &")` will.  However, depending on how complicated the command was and precisely which OS, C library, and `/bin/sh` you have, there might be an intermediate `sh` process hanging around and confusing the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the latter part of the question is more a consideration of the shell, rather than the kernel.  (Simon Urbanek has answered the `multicore` part better than pretty much anyone else could, as he's the author.  :))

If you're using bash, you can find the PID of the most recently launched child process in `$!`.  You can aggregate the PIDs and then be sure to kill those off when you close R.

If you want to be really gonzo, you could store parent PID (i.e. the output of `Sys.getpid()`) and child PID in a file and have a cleaning daemon that checks whether or not the parent PID exists and, if not, kills the orphans.  I don't think it'll be that easy to get a package called `oRphanKilleR` onto CRAN, though.

Here is an example of appending the child PID to a file:

```
system('(sleep 20) & echo $! >> ~/childPIDs.txt', wait = FALSE)
```

You can modify this to create your own shell command and use R's `tempfile()` command to create a temporary file (albeit, that will disappear when the R instance is terminated, unless you take a special effort to preserve the file via permissions).

For some other clever ideas, see [this other post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/bash-script-that-kills-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout).

You can also create a `do while` loop in the shell that will check for whether or not a particular PID is in existence.  While it is, the loop sleeps.  Once the loop terminates (because the PID is no longer in use), the script will kill another PID.

Basically, I think your solution will be in shell scripting, rather than R.