# How to run a process with a timeout in Bash?

Tags: linux, shell, timeout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Bash script that kills a child process after a given timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/bash-script-that-kills-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout)

Is there a way to write a shell script that would execute a certain command for 15 seconds, then kill the command?

I have tried sleep, wait and ping but maybe I am using them wrong.

Comment: Usually you use an ALARM signal and trap it. But the command utility [timelimit](http://devel.ringlet.net/sysutils/timelimit/) looks promising.

Comment: who vote this as offtopic? :/

Answer (score 239):

Use the `timeout` command:

```
timeout 15s command
```

Note: on some systems you need to install `coreutils`, on others it's missing or has different command line arguments. See an alternate solution posted by @ArjunShankar . Based on it you can encapsulate that boiler-plate code and create your own portable `timeout` script or small C app that does the same thing.

Comment: not to mention that it will return instantly if the command finished earlier

Comment: So for the command Im trying to kill after 15 secs I have tried using this command but it didnt stop the command from running, I have also tried using timeout - k 15 and that also didnt work :(

Comment: this is how you **run** the command.

Comment: Where does the `timeout` command come from?  I don't have it on any of the RHEL or Ubuntu servers I'm on.  (Or in FreeBSD or OS X, for that matter.)

Comment: It's in coreutils 8.x on my debian box.

Comment: I have been reading about this, and I find that `timeout` is not the portable way to do this. There are two popular implementations of `timeout` with slightly different features. One is part of [TCT](http://www.porcupine.org/forensics/tct.html) and one part of [coreutils](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html). I have an obscure implementation on an RHEL machine I am on now (I don't maintain it so I don't know who installed this one), and it has a completely different set of flags (e.g. `-t` for setting the timeout).

Comment: @ArjunShankar: thx, I used it with debian, ubuntu, centos and cygwin, all working fine here.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath - Right. I figure that it would only be an occasional machine that doesn't have the coreutils implementation installed.

Comment: Coreutils would be missing from anything that is FreeBSD, NetBSD, OS X, HP/UX, Solaris, AIX, etc.

Comment: With homebrew-installed `coreutils` on OS X, the command is available as `gtimeout`

Comment: this is good for a simple command timeout; however, for quoted arguments and multiple commands, quoting spaghetti begins, e.g. this obtuse example: `timeout 5s sh -c "while true; do echo \"\\\"quoted\\\"\"; sleep 1; done"`

Answer (score 66):

Some machines don't have `timeout` installed/available. In that case, you could background the process; its PID then gets stored as `$!`; then sleep for the required amount of time, then kill it:

```
some_command arg1 arg2 &
TASK_PID=$!
sleep 15
kill $TASK_PID
```

At [this URL](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/068) I find that there are mentioned, more than one solutions to make this happen.

Comment: I initially deleted my answer (because, clearly, Karoly's is so much more awesome), but it appears that some people don't have `timeout` => undeleted.