# How to set timeout in Telnet bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, telnet

I want to run several `Telnet` in a bash script and output the result to different text files.

```
telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.1 | tee -a /home/kristoffer/telnetXXX.XXX.XXX.1.txt
telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.2 | tee -a /home/kristoffer/telnetXXX.XXX.XXX.2.txt
telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.3 | tee -a /home/kristoffer/telnetXXX.XXX.XXX.3.txt
telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.4 | tee -a /home/kristoffer/telnetXXX.XXX.XXX.4.txt
```

This code works fine, but takes a lot of time to execute. I have tried `&` after each row, but then the Telnet aborts to early. I would like to abort each telnet connection after, for example 10 seconds.

Do you know how to do that?

Comment: there are 761 results when searching for `[bash] timeout`. The 2nd one looks very promising for you. good luck.

Comment: I tried to put timeout 10 before each command, but it didn't work. I didn't get the login-text.

Comment: See the answer about the [timeout](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10225072/1563512) command.

Comment: The problem is that I don't get the login text in telnet. It doesn't come up

Answer (score 0):

How about throwing some additional syntax onto the problem:

```
( telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.1 >> /home/kristoffer/telnetXXX.XXX.XXX.1.txt ) &
( telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.2 >> /home/kristoffer/telnetXXX.XXX.XXX.2.txt ) &
( telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.3 >> /home/kristoffer/telnetXXX.XXX.XXX.3.txt ) &
( telnet XXX.XXX.XXX.4 >> /home/kristoffer/telnetXXX.XXX.XXX.4.txt ) &

wait
```