# How to periodically clear unfinished cron jobs

Tags: php, cron

I have scheduled a cron job (which runs a php script) which runs every 15 minutes. This cron job is in dependence of another separate system and code and one day this system crashed so after the weekend I found the server flooded with numerous scheduled jobs.

Can you give me some advice how to avoid such problems? Maybe, to clean similar old cron jobs automatically or something else?

Thank you!

Comment: You could set a timeout for the commands, so that they stop after a certain period of time.

Comment: You mean in my php script - sometling like sleep? Or on the server? My cron now is just */15 * * * * path-to-file-to-run

Comment: I mean a maximum execution time. As described in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10225072/743016.

Comment: Yes,this seems really useful, I will try it, thank you!