# Ctrl C in shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I've got a shell script with the following code;

```
#!/bin/bash
nfcapd -z -w -t30 -p 2055 -l /home/shane/Documents/nfdump
```

My problem is that when I execute the shell script, the command above executes over and over (it captures network traffic from a router), but I'd like for it to stop after 30 seconds. In the terminal I would just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>, is there a way of executing this command (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>) after a certain time t?

Comment: take a look at this-:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/bash-script-that-kills-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `timeout`

```
timeout 30 nfcapd -z -w -t30 -p 2055 -l /home/shane/Documents/nfdump
```

More info [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/timeout-invocation.html)

Answer (score 2):

Put this statement after `#!/bin/bash`

> (sleep 30 ; kill -9 $$ )&

See if it works in your case.

Comment: Almost -1: You must not recommend `-9` here.  Especially given that the question specifically mentions ctrl-C, which sends `SIGINT`.

Answer (score 2):

You may also kill the last job:

```
#! /bin/bash
nfcapd -z -w -t30 -p 2055 -l /home/shane/Documents/nfdump &
sleep 30 ; kill %%
echo "nfcapd terminated"
exit 0
```