# preventing scripts from stopping on errors

Tags: linux, shell

My issue is likely a rather simple one, I just haven't found a satisfactory answer anywhere I've looked so far.

I have a script which runs a program/script, when it encounters an error it just hangs and will not continue along.
**What is the best method to fix this?**

To clarify, usually there is no output when it hangs but sometimes there is an error message, depending on which script I am using to work on my data set.

Example script:

```
#!/bin/bash
# iterate over a NUL-delimited stream of directory names
while IFS='' read -r -d '' dirname; do
  # ...then list files in each directory:
  for file in "$dirname"/*; do
    # ignore directory contents that are not files
    [[ -f $file ]] || continue
    # run analysis tool
    if [[ $file == *.dmp ]]; then
      echo $dirname;
      tshark -PVx -r "$file" >> $dirname/TEXT_out.txt #with packet summary line, packet details expanded, packet bytes
      #ls $dirname;
      echo "complete";
      continue
    fi
  done
done < <(find . -type d -print0)
```

Comment: can tshark provide any sort of exit code or output to signify that it stopped with an error?

Comment: I believe so but I don't really have much expertise with tshark to tell you currently. I would assume stderr.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In nutshell, you are asking - how to handle if the child process hangs (from parent perspective). If that is the basic issue your are facing, then you can check this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/bash-script-that-kills-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout). 
HTH!