# Bash: if command hasn't finished in a given time - change variable

Tags: bash

My program takes two variables (n & k, from 1 to 100).

```
PROGRAM n k INPUT > OUTPUT
```

I want to find out which combination of variables gives the best output. This is my way of doing this:

```
for n in {1..100}; do
   for k in {1..100}; do
       PROGRAM n k INPUT |
       awk -v n="$n" -v k="$k" '{print n,k,$0}' >> OUTPUT # Latter I analyse output and select best combination
   done
done
```

This works perfectly. However some variables (e.g, n from 80 to 90) takes really long time to run.
What I want:
    Run given script for a specific amount of time and if PROGRAM hasn't finished jump to the following variable.
For example:

```
(n=11; k=23) PROGRAM 11 23 INPUT # Runs 59 seconds -- OK
(n=11; k=24) PROGRAM 11 24 INPUT # Runs 34 seconds -- OK
(n=11; k=25) PROGRAM 11 25 INPUT # Already runs 60 seconds -- Too much. End and jump to (n=11; k=26)
(n=11; k=26) PROGRAM 11 26 INPUT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just run your scripts with [timeout](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/man1/timeout.1.html). Install it, e.g. on Ubuntu `sudo apt-get install coreutils`. Then run your script with `timeout DURATION PROGRAM n k INPUT`

```
for n in {1..100}; do
   for k in {1..100}; do
       timeout 60 PROGRAM n k INPUT |
       awk -v n="$n" -v k="$k" '{print n,k,$0}' >> OUTPUT # Latter I analyse output and select best combination
   done
done
```

You can check the return value of timeout if you want to do something then.

```
timeout DURATION PROGRAM n k INPUT
if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
    # it was killed (timeout returns non-zero if it killed the program)
    echo "took too long"
fi
```

Also take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5161258/202504). It shows other ways to launch a process and then timeout, without relying on the timeout program:

(taken from the answer):

```
( cmdpid=$BASHPID; (sleep DURATION; kill $cmdpid) & exec PROGRAM n k INPUT )
```

However, in your case you are running a lot of programs. So this will lead to a lot of running background processes that sleep for DURATION, so this is probably not ideal. The other answer has the same problem.

Comment: TIL linux has a `timeout` command.  Thank you!  Just shows that, even after decades, you're never finished learning linux.  ;-)