# Bash script telnet to test multiple addresses and ports

Tags: bash, shell, unix, telnet, firewall

I am required to test at least 130 ip addresses and ports.
I am hoping to write a bash script such that it reads the ip address and ports from an input file.

I have the following

```
while read line
do
telnet $line >> $2
done < $1
```

This is a crappy code as it cannot determine whether its connected or failed, and I have to rely on its auto escape character to disconnect from a connection.

How can I improvise this such that it updates $2 with the status quickly?
I am working on Redhat and do not have netcat or expect installed..

Comment: Why not just use `nmap`?

Comment: Why not use [Netcat](http://netcat.sourceforge.net/)?

Comment: I tried to use nmap on a ip and port that works. Got the following: Starting Nmap 5.51 ( http://nmap.org ) at 2014-05-02 06:15 UTC
Note: Host seems down. If it is really up, but blocking our ping probes, try -Pn
Nmap done: 1 IP address (0 hosts up) scanned in 3.04 seconds

Comment: do not have root access to install Netcat

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Because OP specifically said that `netcat` is not an option.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As other stackoverflower's said, I would recommend using `nmap` or `netcat` if avilable.
However, if you cannot use those software, you can use bash's builtin `/dev/tcp/<host>/<port>` instead.

http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections

I could'nt figure out which version of bash you are using, but `/dev/tcp/...` seems to implemented since some old bash.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "scanme.nmap.org 21
scanme.nmap.org 22
scanme.nmap.org 23
scanme.nmap.org 79
scanme.nmap.org 80
scanme.nmap.org 81" | \
while read host port; do
  r=$(bash -c 'exec 3<> /dev/tcp/'$host'/'$port';echo $?' 2>/dev/null)
  if [ "$r" = "0" ]; then
    echo $host $port is open
  else
    echo $host $port is closed
  fi
done
```

This produces

```
scanme.nmap.org 21 is closed
scanme.nmap.org 22 is open
scanme.nmap.org 23 is closed
scanme.nmap.org 79 is closed
scanme.nmap.org 80 is open
scanme.nmap.org 81 is closed
```

UPDATED: The following can do timeout.
Although it may seem little tricky, idea is just to kill the child process after some timeout.

[Bash script that kills a child process after a given timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/bash-script-that-kills-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout)

```
#!/bin/bash
echo "scanme.nmap.org 80
scanme.nmap.org 81
192.168.0.100 1" | (
  TCP_TIMEOUT=3
  while read host port; do
    (CURPID=$BASHPID;
    (sleep $TCP_TIMEOUT;kill $CURPID) &
    exec 3<> /dev/tcp/$host/$port
    ) 2>/dev/null
    case $? in
    0)
      echo $host $port is open;;
    1)
      echo $host $port is closed;;
    143) # killed by SIGTERM
       echo $host $port timeouted;;
     esac
  done
  ) 2>/dev/null # avoid bash message "Terminated ..."
```

this produces

```
scanme.nmap.org 80 is open
scanme.nmap.org 81 is closed
192.168.0.100 1 timeouted
```

since 192.168.100 does not exist in my local network.

Comment: Is there a way to also echo those hosts that are unreachable? This is great, but would need to also somehow determine if the server can communicate with the target host
I have several hosts that timeouts

Comment: I added timeout option.

Comment: It was implemented in `bash-2.04-devel` ([ChangeLog](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/CHANGES)) so if you know that you run `bash` and not some other shell it's old enough that you can pretty much rely on having the feature.

Comment: This could be [a lot quicker if run parallelized](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74962185/1765658)!!

Answer (score 0):

A slight update to the accepted answer:

```
#!/bin/bash
# supertelnet 127.0.0.1:3306 10.10.10.45:22
(
  TCP_TIMEOUT=3
  for hostport in ${@}; do
    a=(${hostport//:/ })
    host=${a[0]}
    port=${a[1]}
    (CURPID=$BASHPID;
    (sleep $TCP_TIMEOUT;kill $CURPID) &
    exec 3<> /dev/tcp/$host/$port
    ) 2>/dev/null
    case $? in
    0)
      echo $host $port is open;;
    1)
      echo $host $port is closed;;
    143) # killed by SIGTERM
       echo $host $port timeouted;;
     esac
  done
  ) 2>/dev/null # avoid bash message "Terminated ..."
```

I find this to be a lot more friendly as a script.