# Killing a node process after .exec() in php on mac OS

Tags: php, node.js, macos

I have the following code on a PHP page, which executes a node command for me.

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['button'])) { exec('/usr/local/bin/node DroneNotes/Dronestream/server.js'); } ?>
<form method="POST">
<p>
<input type="hidden" name="button" value="1">
<input type="submit" value="Start Video">
</p>
</form>
```

The command is executing fine for me but the process is just hanging and not stopping for me. Im wondering could I kill the process in some way by creating another button click or can something be added in to end it after a certain time?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that it is a good idea to start a server for each client...  if you have 100 clients in same time, you will start 100 times your server.js ? did you think about using differents port ?

To respond to your question: you have to create a script shell, that it starts your server, and it can killing it after period of time.

There are a good examples here to do your job [Bash script that kills a child process after a given timeout](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/bash-script-that-kills-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout)

Answer (score 0):

Check out this question to exit Node.js at the end of the process;

[How to exit in Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5266152/how-to-exit-in-node-js)

Or you can use "[forever](https://www.npmjs.com/package/forever)" to start and stop a node.js server manually;

```
forever start DroneNotes/Dronestream/server.js

forever stop DroneNotes/Dronestream/server.js
```

Comment: I think the forever stop might work for me best in this situation. Could I add this in as a new button on the webpage and it would stop the server for me ?

Comment: Yes, I believe you can exec it like you do in your sample code but please consider the answer below if that is the right way to do it. I don't know what you are trying to do but if you click that submit button twice unless you change the port you will get a ENOENT error because port can only be used with one server process.