# Bash multiple files processing

Tags: bash

I have a file named data_file with data:
london
paris
newyork
italy...50 more items

Have a directory with over 75 files, say dfile1, dfie2...afle75 in which i am performing search for entries in data_file.

```
files=$(find . -type f)

for f in $files; do
   while read -r line; do
       found=$(grep $line $f)      

       if [ ! -z "$found" ]; then
          perform task here
       fi
   done < data_file 
done
```

As the loop runs for each file one by one, it takes lots of time to finish. How can I speed it up, can i run the for loop for multiple files at same time?

Comment: `if [ ! -z "found" ]` This will always pass; did you mean `if [ ! -z $found ]`?  Or even better, you could use `grep -q` and check the value of `$?`.

Comment: Have a look at the GNU `parallel` tool. It's like `xargs` but parallel.

Comment: Can you be specific about the `task` performed in the loop? The optimization approach may depend on it.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU Parallel you can do something like this:

```
doit() {
    f="$1"
    line="$2"
    found=$(grep $line $f)      

    if [ ! -z "$found" ]; then
      perform task here
    fi
}
export -f doit

find . -type f | parallel doit :::: - data_file
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example is a full blown parallel execution method, that deals with:

- Execution time (will warn after a certain execution time, and stop tasks after more time has passed)
- Async logging (keeps logging what's going on while tasks being executed)
- Parallelism (allows to specify the number of simultaneous tasks)
- IO related zombie tasks (will not block the execution)
- Does handle killing of grand children pids
- Lots of more stuff

In your example, your (hardened) code would look like:

```sh
# Load the ExecTasks function described below (must be in the same directory as this one)
source ./exectasks.sh

directoryToProcess="/my/dir/to/find/stuff/into"
tasklist=""

# Prepare task list separated by semicolumn
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' file; do
    if grep "$line" "$file" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
         tasklist="$tasklist""my_task;"
done < <(find "$directoryToProcess" -type f -print0)

# Run tasks
ExecTasks "$tasklist" "trivial-task-id" false 1800 3600 18000 36000 true 1 1800 true false false 8
```

Here we used a complex function ExecTasks that will deal with parallel queueing the tasks, and let you keep control of what's going on without fear to block the script because of some hanged task.

Quick explanation of ExecTasks arguments:

```
"$tasklist" = variable containing task list
"some name" trivial task id (in order to identify in logs)
boolean: read tasks from file (you may have passed a task list from a file if there are too many to fit in a variable
1800 = maximum number of seconds a task may be executed before a warning is raised
3600 = maximum number of seconds a task may be executed before an error is raised and the tasks is stopped 
18000 = maximum number of seconds the whole tasks may be executed before a warning is raised 
36000 = maximum number of seconds the whole tasks may be executed before an error is raised and all the tasks are stopped
boolean: account execution time since beginning of tasks execution (true) or since script begin
1 = number of seconds between each state check (accepts float like .1)
1800 = Number of seconds between each "i am alive" log just to know everything works as expected
boolean: show spinner (true) or not (false) 
boolean: log errors when reaching max times (false) or do not log them (true)
boolean: do not log any errors at all (false) or do log them (true)

And finally
8 = number of simultaneous tasks to launch (8 in our case)
```

Here's the source to exectasks.sh (which you can also copy paste directly into your script header instead of `source ./exectasks.sh`):

```
function Logger {
    # Dummy log function, replace with whatever you need

    echo "$2: $1"
}

# Nice cli spinner so we now execution is ongoing
_OFUNCTIONS_SPINNER="|/-\\"
function Spinner {
    printf " [%c]  \b\b\b\b\b\b" "$_OFUNCTIONS_SPINNER"
    _OFUNCTIONS_SPINNER=${_OFUNCTIONS_SPINNER#?}${_OFUNCTIONS_SPINNER%%???}
    return 0
}

# Portable child (and grandchild) kill function tester under Linux, BSD and MacOS X
function KillChilds {
    local pid="${1}" # Parent pid to kill childs
    local self="${2:-false}" # Should parent be killed too ?

    # Paranoid checks, we can safely assume that $pid should not be 0 nor 1
    if [ $(IsInteger "$pid") -eq 0 ] || [ "$pid" == "" ] || [ "$pid" == "0" ] || [ "$pid" == "1" ]; then
        Logger "Bogus pid given [$pid]." "CRITICAL"
        return 1
    fi

    if kill -0 "$pid" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
        if children="$(pgrep -P "$pid")"; then
            if [[ "$pid" == *"$children"* ]]; then
                Logger "Bogus pgrep implementation." "CRITICAL"
                children="${children/$pid/}"
            fi
            for child in $children; do
                Logger "Launching KillChilds \"$child\" true" "DEBUG"   #__WITH_PARANOIA_DEBUG
                KillChilds "$child" true
            done
        fi
    fi

    # Try to kill nicely, if not, wait 15 seconds to let Trap actions happen before killing
    if [ "$self" == true ]; then
        # We need to check for pid again because it may have disappeared after recursive function call
        if kill -0 "$pid" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
            kill -s TERM "$pid"
            Logger "Sent SIGTERM to process [$pid]." "DEBUG"
            if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                sleep 15
                Logger "Sending SIGTERM to process [$pid] failed." "DEBUG"
                kill -9 "$pid"
                if [ $? -ne 0 ]; then
                    Logger "Sending SIGKILL to process [$pid] failed." "DEBUG"
                    return 1
                fi  # Simplify the return 0 logic here
            else
                return 0
            fi
        else
            return 0
        fi
    else
        return 0
    fi
}


function ExecTasks {
    # Mandatory arguments
    local mainInput="${1}"              # Contains list of pids / commands separated by semicolons or filepath to list of pids / commands

    # Optional arguments
    local id="${2:-base}"               # Optional ID in order to identify global variables from this run (only bash variable names, no '-'). Global variables are WAIT_FOR_TASK_COMPLETION_$id and HARD_MAX_EXEC_TIME_REACHED_$id
    local readFromFile="${3:-false}"        # Is mainInput / auxInput a semicolon separated list (true) or a filepath (false)
    local softPerProcessTime="${4:-0}"      # Max time (in seconds) a pid or command can run before a warning is logged, unless set to 0
    local hardPerProcessTime="${5:-0}"      # Max time (in seconds) a pid or command can run before the given command / pid is stopped, unless set to 0
    local softMaxTime="${6:-0}"         # Max time (in seconds) for the whole function to run before a warning is logged, unless set to 0
    local hardMaxTime="${7:-0}"         # Max time (in seconds) for the whole function to run before all pids / commands given are stopped, unless set to 0
    local counting="${8:-true}"         # Should softMaxTime and hardMaxTime be accounted since function begin (true) or since script begin (false)
    local sleepTime="${9:-.5}"          # Seconds between each state check. The shorter the value, the snappier ExecTasks will be, but as a tradeoff, more cpu power will be used (good values are between .05 and 1)
    local keepLogging="${10:-1800}"         # Every keepLogging seconds, an alive message is logged. Setting this value to zero disables any alive logging
    local spinner="${11:-true}"         # Show spinner (true) or do not show anything (false) while running
    local noTimeErrorLog="${12:-false}"     # Log errors when reaching soft / hard execution times (false) or do not log errors on those triggers (true)
    local noErrorLogsAtAll="${13:-false}"       # Do not log any errros at all (useful for recursive ExecTasks checks)

    # Parallelism specific arguments
    local numberOfProcesses="${14:-0}"      # Number of simulanteous commands to run, given as mainInput. Set to 0 by default (WaitForTaskCompletion mode). Setting this value enables ParallelExec mode.
    local auxInput="${15}"              # Contains list of commands separated by semicolons or filepath fo list of commands. Exit code of those commands decide whether main commands will be executed or not
    local maxPostponeRetries="${16:-3}"     # If a conditional command fails, how many times shall we try to postpone the associated main command. Set this to 0 to disable postponing
    local minTimeBetweenRetries="${17:-300}"    # Time (in seconds) between postponed command retries
    local validExitCodes="${18:-0}"         # Semi colon separated list of valid main command exit codes which will not trigger errors

    local i

    # Expand validExitCodes into array
    IFS=';' read -r -a validExitCodes <<< "$validExitCodes"

    # ParallelExec specific variables
    local auxItemCount=0        # Number of conditional commands
    local commandsArray=()      # Array containing commands
    local commandsConditionArray=() # Array containing conditional commands
    local currentCommand        # Variable containing currently processed command
    local currentCommandCondition   # Variable containing currently processed conditional command
    local commandsArrayPid=()   # Array containing commands indexed by pids
    local commandsArrayOutput=()    # Array containing command results indexed by pids
    local postponedRetryCount=0 # Number of current postponed commands retries
    local postponedItemCount=0  # Number of commands that have been postponed (keep at least one in order to check once)
    local postponedCounter=0
    local isPostponedCommand=false  # Is the current command from a postponed file ?
    local postponedExecTime=0   # How much time has passed since last postponed condition was checked
    local needsPostponing       # Does currentCommand need to be postponed
    local temp

    # Common variables
    local pid           # Current pid working on
    local pidState          # State of the process
    local mainItemCount=0       # number of given items (pids or commands)
    local readFromFile      # Should we read pids / commands from a file (true)
    local counter=0
    local log_ttime=0       # local time instance for comparaison

    local seconds_begin=$SECONDS    # Seconds since the beginning of the script
    local exec_time=0       # Seconds since the beginning of this function

    local retval=0          # return value of monitored pid process
    local subRetval=0       # return value of condition commands
    local errorcount=0      # Number of pids that finished with errors
    local pidsArray         # Array of currently running pids
    local newPidsArray      # New array of currently running pids for next iteration
    local pidsTimeArray     # Array containing execution begin time of pids
    local executeCommand        # Boolean to check if currentCommand can be executed given a condition

    local functionMode
    local softAlert=false       # Does a soft alert need to be triggered, if yes, send an alert once
    local failedPidsList        # List containing failed pids with exit code separated by semicolons (eg : 2355:1;4534:2;2354:3)
    local randomOutputName      # Random filename for command outputs
    local currentRunningPids    # String of pids running, used for debugging purposes only

    # fnver 2019081401

    # Initialise global variable
    eval "WAIT_FOR_TASK_COMPLETION_$id=\"\""
    eval "HARD_MAX_EXEC_TIME_REACHED_$id=false"

    # Init function variables depending on mode

    if [ $numberOfProcesses -gt 0 ]; then
        functionMode=ParallelExec
    else
        functionMode=WaitForTaskCompletion
    fi

    if [ $readFromFile == false ]; then
        if [ $functionMode == "WaitForTaskCompletion" ]; then
            IFS=';' read -r -a pidsArray <<< "$mainInput"
            mainItemCount="${#pidsArray[@]}"
        else
            IFS=';' read -r -a commandsArray <<< "$mainInput"
            mainItemCount="${#commandsArray[@]}"
            IFS=';' read -r -a commandsConditionArray <<< "$auxInput"
            auxItemCount="${#commandsConditionArray[@]}"
        fi
    else
        if [ -f "$mainInput" ]; then
            mainItemCount=$(wc -l < "$mainInput")
            readFromFile=true
        else
            Logger "Cannot read main file [$mainInput]." "WARN"
        fi
        if [ "$auxInput" != "" ]; then
            if [ -f "$auxInput" ]; then
                auxItemCount=$(wc -l < "$auxInput")
            else
                Logger "Cannot read aux file [$auxInput]." "WARN"
            fi
        fi
    fi

    if [ $functionMode == "WaitForTaskCompletion" ]; then
        # Force first while loop condition to be true because we don't deal with counters but pids in WaitForTaskCompletion mode
        counter=$mainItemCount
    fi


    # soft / hard execution time checks that needs to be a subfunction since it is called both from main loop and from parallelExec sub loop
    function _ExecTasksTimeCheck {
        if [ $spinner == true ]; then
            Spinner
        fi
        if [ $counting == true ]; then
            exec_time=$((SECONDS - seconds_begin))
        else
            exec_time=$SECONDS
        fi

        if [ $keepLogging -ne 0 ]; then
            # This log solely exists for readability purposes before having next set of logs
            if [ ${#pidsArray[@]} -eq $numberOfProcesses ] && [ $log_ttime -eq 0 ]; then
                log_ttime=$exec_time
                Logger "There are $((mainItemCount-counter+postponedItemCount)) / $mainItemCount tasks in the queue of which $postponedItemCount are postponed. Currently, ${#pidsArray[@]} tasks running with pids [$(joinString , ${pidsArray[@]})]." "NOTICE"
            fi
            if [ $(((exec_time + 1) % keepLogging)) -eq 0 ]; then
                if [ $log_ttime -ne $exec_time ]; then # Fix when sleep time lower than 1 second
                    log_ttime=$exec_time
                    if [ $functionMode == "WaitForTaskCompletion" ]; then
                        Logger "Current tasks still running with pids [$(joinString , ${pidsArray[@]})]." "NOTICE"
                    elif [ $functionMode == "ParallelExec" ]; then
                        Logger "There are $((mainItemCount-counter+postponedItemCount)) / $mainItemCount tasks in the queue of which $postponedItemCount are postponed. Currently, ${#pidsArray[@]} tasks running with pids [$(joinString , ${pidsArray[@]})]." "NOTICE"
                    fi
                fi
            fi
        fi

        if [ $exec_time -gt $softMaxTime ]; then
            if [ "$softAlert" != true ] && [ $softMaxTime -ne 0 ] && [ $noTimeErrorLog != true ]; then
                Logger "Max soft execution time [$softMaxTime] exceeded for task [$id] with pids [$(joinString , ${pidsArray[@]})]." "WARN"
                softAlert=true
                SendAlert true
            fi
        fi

        if [ $exec_time -gt $hardMaxTime ] && [ $hardMaxTime -ne 0 ]; then
            if [ $noTimeErrorLog != true ]; then
                Logger "Max hard execution time [$hardMaxTime] exceeded for task [$id] with pids [$(joinString , ${pidsArray[@]})]. Stopping task execution." "ERROR"
            fi
            for pid in "${pidsArray[@]}"; do
                KillChilds $pid true
                if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                    Logger "Task with pid [$pid] stopped successfully." "NOTICE"
                else
                    if [ $noErrorLogsAtAll != true ]; then
                        Logger "Could not stop task with pid [$pid]." "ERROR"
                    fi
                fi
                errorcount=$((errorcount+1))
            done
            if [ $noTimeErrorLog != true ]; then
                SendAlert true
            fi
            eval "HARD_MAX_EXEC_TIME_REACHED_$id=true"
            if [ $functionMode == "WaitForTaskCompletion" ]; then
                return $errorcount
            else
                return 129
            fi
        fi
    }

    function _ExecTasksPidsCheck {
        newPidsArray=()

        if [ "$currentRunningPids" != "$(joinString " " ${pidsArray[@]})" ]; then
            Logger "ExecTask running for pids [$(joinString " " ${pidsArray[@]})]." "DEBUG"
            currentRunningPids="$(joinString " " ${pidsArray[@]})"
        fi

        for pid in "${pidsArray[@]}"; do
            if [ $(IsInteger $pid) -eq 1 ]; then
                if kill -0 $pid > /dev/null 2>&1; then
                    # Handle uninterruptible sleep state or zombies by ommiting them from running process array (How to kill that is already dead ? :)
                    pidState="$(eval $PROCESS_STATE_CMD)"
                    if [ "$pidState" != "D" ] && [ "$pidState" != "Z" ]; then

                        # Check if pid hasn't run more than soft/hard perProcessTime
                        pidsTimeArray[$pid]=$((SECONDS - seconds_begin))
                        if [ ${pidsTimeArray[$pid]} -gt $softPerProcessTime ]; then
                            if [ "$softAlert" != true ] && [ $softPerProcessTime -ne 0 ] && [ $noTimeErrorLog != true ]; then
                                Logger "Max soft execution time [$softPerProcessTime] exceeded for pid [$pid]." "WARN"
                                if [ "${commandsArrayPid[$pid]}]" != "" ]; then
                                    Logger "Command was [${commandsArrayPid[$pid]}]]." "WARN"
                                fi
                                softAlert=true
                                SendAlert true
                            fi
                        fi


                        if [ ${pidsTimeArray[$pid]} -gt $hardPerProcessTime ] && [ $hardPerProcessTime -ne 0 ]; then
                            if [ $noTimeErrorLog != true ] && [ $noErrorLogsAtAll != true ]; then
                                Logger "Max hard execution time [$hardPerProcessTime] exceeded for pid [$pid]. Stopping command execution." "ERROR"
                                if [ "${commandsArrayPid[$pid]}]" != "" ]; then
                                    Logger "Command was [${commandsArrayPid[$pid]}]]." "WARN"
                                fi
                            fi
                            KillChilds $pid true
                            if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
                                 Logger "Command with pid [$pid] stopped successfully." "NOTICE"
                            else
                                if [ $noErrorLogsAtAll != true ]; then
                                Logger "Could not stop command with pid [$pid]." "ERROR"
                                fi
                            fi
                            errorcount=$((errorcount+1))

                            if [ $noTimeErrorLog != true ]; then
                                SendAlert true
                            fi
                        fi

                        newPidsArray+=($pid)
                    fi
                else
                    # pid is dead, get its exit code from wait command
                    wait $pid
                    retval=$?
                    # Check for valid exit codes
                    if [ $(ArrayContains $retval "${validExitCodes[@]}") -eq 0 ]; then
                        if [ $noErrorLogsAtAll != true ]; then
                            Logger "${FUNCNAME[0]} called by [$id] finished monitoring pid [$pid] with exitcode [$retval]." "ERROR"
                            if [ "$functionMode" == "ParallelExec" ]; then
                                Logger "Command was [${commandsArrayPid[$pid]}]." "ERROR"
                            fi
                            if [ -f "${commandsArrayOutput[$pid]}" ]; then
                                Logger "Truncated output:\n$(head -c16384 "${commandsArrayOutput[$pid]}")" "ERROR"
                            fi
                        fi
                        errorcount=$((errorcount+1))
                        # Welcome to variable variable bash hell
                        if [ "$failedPidsList" == "" ]; then
                            failedPidsList="$pid:$retval"
                        else
                            failedPidsList="$failedPidsList;$pid:$retval"
                        fi
                    else
                        Logger "${FUNCNAME[0]} called by [$id] finished monitoring pid [$pid] with exitcode [$retval]." "DEBUG"
                    fi
                fi
            fi
        done

        # hasPids can be false on last iteration in ParallelExec mode
        pidsArray=("${newPidsArray[@]}")

        # Trivial wait time for bash to not eat up all CPU
        sleep $sleepTime
    }

    while [ ${#pidsArray[@]} -gt 0 ] || [ $counter -lt $mainItemCount ] || [ $postponedItemCount -ne 0 ]; do
        _ExecTasksTimeCheck
        retval=$?
        if [ $retval -ne 0 ]; then
            return $retval;
        fi

        # The following execution bloc is only needed in ParallelExec mode since WaitForTaskCompletion does not execute commands, but only monitors them
        if [ $functionMode == "ParallelExec" ]; then
            while [ ${#pidsArray[@]} -lt $numberOfProcesses ] && ([ $counter -lt $mainItemCount ] || [ $postponedItemCount -ne 0 ]); do
                _ExecTasksTimeCheck
                retval=$?
                if [ $retval -ne 0 ]; then
                    return $retval;
                fi

                executeCommand=false
                isPostponedCommand=false
                currentCommand=""
                currentCommandCondition=""
                needsPostponing=false

                if [ $readFromFile == true ]; then
                    # awk identifies first line as 1 instead of 0 so we need to increase counter
                    currentCommand=$(awk 'NR == num_line {print; exit}' num_line=$((counter+1)) "$mainInput")
                    if [ $auxItemCount -ne 0 ]; then
                        currentCommandCondition=$(awk 'NR == num_line {print; exit}' num_line=$((counter+1)) "$auxInput")
                    fi

                    # Check if we need to fetch postponed commands
                    if [ "$currentCommand" == "" ]; then
                        currentCommand=$(awk 'NR == num_line {print; exit}' num_line=$((postponedCounter+1)) "$RUN_DIR/$PROGRAM.${FUNCNAME[0]}-postponedMain.$id.$SCRIPT_PID.$TSTAMP")
                        currentCommandCondition=$(awk 'NR == num_line {print; exit}' num_line=$((postponedCounter+1)) "$RUN_DIR/$PROGRAM.${FUNCNAME[0]}-postponedAux.$id.$SCRIPT_PID.$TSTAMP")
                        isPostponedCommand=true
                    fi
                else
                    currentCommand="${commandsArray[$counter]}"
                    if [ $auxItemCount -ne 0 ]; then
                        currentCommandCondition="${commandsConditionArray[$counter]}"
                    fi

                    if [ "$currentCommand" == "" ]; then
                        currentCommand="${postponedCommandsArray[$postponedCounter]}"
                        currentCommandCondition="${postponedCommandsConditionArray[$postponedCounter]}"
                        isPostponedCommand=true
                    fi
                fi

                # Check if we execute postponed commands, or if we delay them
                if [ $isPostponedCommand == true ]; then
                    # Get first value before '@'
                    postponedExecTime="${currentCommand%%@*}"
                    postponedExecTime=$((SECONDS-postponedExecTime))
                    # Get everything after first '@'
                    temp="${currentCommand#*@}"
                    # Get first value before '@'
                    postponedRetryCount="${temp%%@*}"
                    # Replace currentCommand with actual filtered currentCommand
                    currentCommand="${temp#*@}"

                    # Since we read a postponed command, we may decrase postponedItemCounter
                    postponedItemCount=$((postponedItemCount-1))
                    #Since we read one line, we need to increase the counter
                    postponedCounter=$((postponedCounter+1))

                else
                    postponedRetryCount=0
                    postponedExecTime=0
                fi
                if ([ $postponedRetryCount -lt $maxPostponeRetries ] && [ $postponedExecTime -ge $minTimeBetweenRetries ]) || [ $isPostponedCommand == false ]; then
                    if [ "$currentCommandCondition" != "" ]; then
                        Logger "Checking condition [$currentCommandCondition] for command [$currentCommand]." "DEBUG"
                        eval "$currentCommandCondition" &
                        ExecTasks $! "subConditionCheck" false 0 0 1800 3600 true $SLEEP_TIME $KEEP_LOGGING true true true
                        subRetval=$?
                        if [ $subRetval -ne 0 ]; then
                            # is postponing enabled ?
                            if [ $maxPostponeRetries -gt 0 ]; then
                                Logger "Condition [$currentCommandCondition] not met for command [$currentCommand]. Exit code [$subRetval]. Postponing command." "NOTICE"
                                postponedRetryCount=$((postponedRetryCount+1))
                                if [ $postponedRetryCount -ge $maxPostponeRetries ]; then
                                    Logger "Max retries reached for postponed command [$currentCommand]. Skipping command." "NOTICE"
                                else
                                    needsPostponing=true
                                fi
                                postponedExecTime=0
                            else
                                Logger "Condition [$currentCommandCondition] not met for command [$currentCommand]. Exit code [$subRetval]. Ignoring command." "NOTICE"
                            fi
                        else
                            executeCommand=true
                        fi
                    else
                        executeCommand=true
                    fi
                else
                    needsPostponing=true
                fi

                if [ $needsPostponing == true ]; then
                    postponedItemCount=$((postponedItemCount+1))
                    if [ $readFromFile == true ]; then
                        echo "$((SECONDS-postponedExecTime))@$postponedRetryCount@$currentCommand" >> "$RUN_DIR/$PROGRAM.${FUNCNAME[0]}-postponedMain.$id.$SCRIPT_PID.$TSTAMP"
                        echo "$currentCommandCondition" >> "$RUN_DIR/$PROGRAM.${FUNCNAME[0]}-postponedAux.$id.$SCRIPT_PID.$TSTAMP"
                    else
                        postponedCommandsArray+=("$((SECONDS-postponedExecTime))@$postponedRetryCount@$currentCommand")
                        postponedCommandsConditionArray+=("$currentCommandCondition")
                    fi
                fi

                if [ $executeCommand == true ]; then
                    Logger "Running command [$currentCommand]." "DEBUG"
                    randomOutputName=$(date '+%Y%m%dT%H%M%S').$(PoorMansRandomGenerator 5)
                    eval "$currentCommand" >> "$RUN_DIR/$PROGRAM.${FUNCNAME[0]}.$id.$pid.$randomOutputName.$SCRIPT_PID.$TSTAMP" 2>&1 &
                    pid=$!
                    pidsArray+=($pid)
                    commandsArrayPid[$pid]="$currentCommand"
                    commandsArrayOutput[$pid]="$RUN_DIR/$PROGRAM.${FUNCNAME[0]}.$id.$pid.$randomOutputName.$SCRIPT_PID.$TSTAMP"
                    # Initialize pid execution time array
                    pidsTimeArray[$pid]=0
                else
                    Logger "Skipping command [$currentCommand]." "DEBUG"
                fi

                if [ $isPostponedCommand == false ]; then
                    counter=$((counter+1))
                fi
                _ExecTasksPidsCheck
            done
        fi

    _ExecTasksPidsCheck
    done

    # Return exit code if only one process was monitored, else return number of errors
    # As we cannot return multiple values, a global variable WAIT_FOR_TASK_COMPLETION contains all pids with their return value

    eval "WAIT_FOR_TASK_COMPLETION_$id=\"$failedPidsList\""

    if [ $mainItemCount -eq 1 ]; then
        return $retval
    else
        return $errorcount
    fi
}
```

Hope you have fun.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it like this :

```
files=$(find . -type f)

for f in $files; do
   while read -r line; do
       {
           found=$(grep $line $f)      

            if [ ! -z "$found" ]; then
                ## perform task here
            fi
       } &
   done < data_file 
done
wait
```

It will execute the block within *{}* in the background. So basically it will open as many background processes as files you have. If you want finer control over how many processes are actually spawned you can instead use **parallel**.

Answer (score -1):

You could use grep's `q` option to stop searching after the first match and `f` option to obtain the patterns from a file:

```
for f in $(find . -type f); do
    if $(grep -qf data_file "$f"); then
        ...
    fi
done
```

If `data_file` contains:

```
xxx
yyy
zzz
```

then `grep -qf "$data_file" "$f"` evaluates to true if either `xxx`, `yyy`, or `zzz` are found in `$f`.

Answer (score -1):

The find command will slow things down and the script is more complicated than it needs to be.

If you want to do this with grep, better to loop through data_file and within that `grep $line * > /dev/null && do_something` (or `grep -R $line * > /dev/null && do_something` if there are subdirectories to deal with)