# SSH Connection & Commands using PLINK with Powershell

Tags: powershell, plink

I'm trying to create a simple script which run a command and send the output to a variable.
this is the script:

```
$output = &"<Path to PLINK>\PLINK.exe" -ssh <username>@<IP Address> -pw <password> "my command"
```

the thing is the command im running is like "top" in linux - a task manager which won't quit until enter is being pressed.

how can i take the CLI output from that situation without touching my keyboard?

i wrote an automation with opening cmd and sending "keys" function inorder to get what i want but i cannot get the output from the CLI by doing so. (also i dont beleive its the right way.)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So execute the command in a way that it won't run infinitely. See [How to kill a child process after a given timeout in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5161193/850848).

Comment: @MartinPrikryl - sadly that solution didnt work for me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my issue by installing POSH-SSH module for Powershell.

Answer (score -1):

As I saw in the following page:
[Run As Admin](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/running-a-script-to-open-a-program-as-administrator/)

using the following code will run the programm PLINK.EXE for you.

```
$Username = 'Username'
$Password = 'Password'
$SecurePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString $Password -AsPlainText -Force
$Credential = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ($Username,$SecurePassword)

Start-Process powershell.exe  -Credential $Credential -NoNewWindow -ArgumentList "(Start-Process -FilePath '\\some\path\app.exe' -ArgumentList  '/q).ExitCode"
```

Comment: i couldnt understand where do i set my SSH connection string and the command.