# Run Cron Job every 5 minutes for 10 seconds

Tags: linux, ubuntu, cron, cron-task

I have a script that I want to run **every 5 minutes for 10 seconds**.

```
*/5 * * * * /root/XXX/cronjobs/add-prod.sh
```

It seems logical to have another cron job that would run every 5 minutes and 10 seconds
that would turn off the 1st cron job.

Something like this:

```
[FORMULA HERE] /root/XXX/cronjobs/rem-prod.sh
```

How can we set a formula for "every 5 minutes and 10 seconds" ?

Comment: Instead of killing the first cronjob with the second, why don't you make the add-prod.sh kill itself after 10 seconds. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5161193/how-to-kill-a-child-process-after-a-given-timeout-in-bash

Answer (score -1):

You can do this via `timeout`. It will kill the process after 10 seconds. It would be better than killing the process externally. Otherwise, jakob22's answer is the best one.

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/timeout 10 /root/XXX/cronjobs/add-prod.sh
```

Edit: This is already featured in a comment.