# break loop after 'n' minutes

Tags: shell, scripting

I am copying a file using `dd` command:

```
dd if=in.dat of=out.dat bs=1kb
```

Suppose the input file is very big and the complete copy will take say 5 min to complete.
I want to break `dd` command after 1 min.

How to achieve this in shell script?

Comment: You're quite content to just copy 20% of the data and stop there?

Comment: While I've been surprised by the amount of things `bash(1)` can do, I have trouble seeing an "easy" way to do this wish `bash(1)`. Another tool such as Ruby, Python, Perl, C, would probably be easier.

Comment: BTW, I guess `op=` is a typo. It must be `of=`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [script to time limit process on posix](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4355396/script-to-time-limit-process-on-posix)

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
dd if=a.dat of=b.dat bs=1kb &
p=$!
sleep 60
kill -9 $p
```

Comment: Any ideas how to run more quickly if the `dd` finishes in ten seconds?

Comment: Oh you could sleep for fewer seconds (in a loop that adds up to 60s) and check if process with PID `$p` is still running.

Comment: Thanks. So the '&' in the end makes dd to execute as if it is a different background process ? so our script will sleep for 60sec but dd will be executing in the background. Thanks thats exactly what i am looking for.

Comment: Using `kill -9` is a very violent way of killing processes.  Use plain `kill`; it sends a SIGTERM signal which is much more appropriate.

Comment: Care to elaborate? SIGTERM can be ignored but SIGKILL can't be. What do you mean by violent? There is absolutely nothing wrong in using SIGKILL if that is your intention.

Comment: @skjaidev SIGKILL doesn't allow the process to terminate gracefully. It's akin to cutting the phone line instead of telling the party on the other end that you're going to hang up now.

Comment: That part is obvious. Why is SIGKILL bad _in this case_? Its not like dd creates temp files.

Comment: @skjaidev I like to think of it like a cop, use only as much force as necessary. It's also not like `dd` ignores SIGTERM

Answer (score 2):

Kill the most recently backgrounded process via `$!` after 60 seconds

```
dd if=a.dat of=b.dat bs=1kb &
sleep 60 && kill $!
```

Comment: Any ideas how to run more quickly if the `dd` finishes in ten seconds?

Comment: Nitpik: OP wants to kill after 1 minute ;-)